# What's the security used in my school network

Tags: windows-7, linux, networking, security

In my school we have to use the school computers to our homework. I like to work on my machine because I have all well configured (Vim, Firefox and I use Ubuntu instead of Windows ...etc). I use my machine to work but the only problem is I don't have Internet. The school computers are connected to Internet via Ethernet cables. So I use my computer to do my work and the computer school to use Internet.

So I decided to plug the cable to my computer but I can’t obtain the IP address so I not even connected to the network. I also changed my MAC address to the one of my school computer but I have the same problem.

To use The school computers we have to connect to our Windows account (it doesn't work if we are not connected to the network).

What’s the technology used in my school? What can I do to solve my problem?

Comment: 802.1x is a possibility. I don’t know how you would detect it, though. Internet access is probably going through a proxy anyway.

Comment: You should talk to your school's IT support and see if they will allow you to use your own computer ...

Comment: The first place to start might be just asking the network administrator for advice.  They might be hesitant to connect a non-school computer to the network because one of their big priorities is to protect the network from infection and they have no control over what your computer is exposed to on the outside.  However, they might be amenable to adding some of your own software choices on your school computer, or perhaps running it in a VM, or even booting the school computer with Ubuntu on an external drive.  They will need to be comfortable that the network is protected.

Answer (score 1):

I want to advise that the controls are based on MAC address but you state:

> I also changed my MAC address to the one of my school computer but I
>   have the same problem.

Could it be that you are changing the MAC address to a system that already had an IP so the router won’t let you login? Meaning you would have to shut down the other computer before doing MAC-spoofing on your machine. Or perhaps it’s a combination of MAC address as well as a static IP?

But you also say this:

> What’s the technology used in my school? What can I do to solve my
>   problem?

The reality is we cannot help you here. We are not at your school. But if you are smart enough to setup your own machine to your liking, you are at a critical juncture here where there are two real choices:

1. Continue to hack around the school network until you figure out how to get in.
2. Contact the school I.T. department and explain what you want to do and why.

As someone who has worked in I.T. for many years, my reaction to someone hacking a network for their own use is to really just block them if they are caught. Why? Easy. I generally expect anyone with deep skills to take the path outlined in point 2, which basically is honest and transparent about who you are and what you want to do.

In general, if someone comes up to me and asks—as well as explains—what they are attempting to do on a system I manage, chances are I will work with them to make us all happy. And the bonus on your side is you actually come off looking as someone who is cooperative and helpful rather than someone who is a security risk.

My best advice? Talk to a human being in your school about your access needs as well as why you feel you need to use your own setup. Chances are you will impress them with your maturity as well as your technical skills.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, only Mac Addresses that are known are allowed to browse the internet. It's a policy that's used in many, many schools.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that your school computer network is configured with AD. Where the systems added in the AD can connect it and do browsing and data transfer inside the LAN. For adding your machine in the network you have to ask your school system administrator.

In some case check whether you have set any static ip in your machine (mostly it wont be). Change the ip4 settings to automatically obtaining IP address and DHCP gateway from metwork.

Note : Check in your school machine at what ip and gate way it is connecting. If it is DHCP connection and not static ip then you can also connect you machine with same configuration